# Cylindrical universe cosmology in general relativity

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, symmetry, metric-tensor, topology

Is there a compact *cylindrical universe* solution to the Einstein equation, with space homogeneity, without using "artificial" periodic boundaries?  I'm expecting a metric of the following shape:
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
ds^2 = f^2(t, r) \, dt^2 - g^2(t, r)(dx^2 + dy^2) - b^2(t) \, dz^2,
\end{equation}
where $f(t, r)$, $g(t, r)$ and $b(t)$ are some functions and $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$.  I'm also expecting $f(t, r) = 1$ and $g(t, r) = a(t) \, g(r)$.  The cylindrical planar space section (coordinates $x$ and $y$) should be homogeneous and compact.

I'm thinking of something similar to a 2D version of the *spherical closed universe* in cosmology ($k = +1$), with an extra space dimension, of FLRW metric
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
ds^2 = dt^2 - \frac{a^2(t)}{(1 + r^2 / 4)^2}(dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2) - b^2(t) \, du^2.
\end{equation}

The metric (1) I'm looking for would have an *homogeneous* 3D space, would be 2D *isotropic* in the cylindrical plane (in coordinates $x$ and $y$), but would not be isotropic in 3D.

---

**EDIT 2 (I've fixed some important mistakes):**
If I assume $f(t, r) = 1$ and $g(t, r) = a(t) \, g(r)$, I could compute the Christoffel symbols and get these (all the other symbols are trivially 0.  Here:  $i, j, k = 1, 2$ for coordinates $x$ and $y$):
\begin{align}
\Gamma_{ij}^0 &= a \dot{a} g^2 \, \delta_{ij}, \\[12pt]
\Gamma_{33}^0 &= b \dot{b}, \\[12pt]
\Gamma_{0 j}^i &= \frac{\dot{a}}{a} \, \delta_{ij}, \\[12pt]
\Gamma_{jk}^i &= \frac{1}{g}(\partial_j g \, \delta_{ik} + \partial_k g \, \delta_{ij} - \partial_i \, g \, \delta_{jk}), \\[12pt]
\Gamma_{03}^3 &= \frac{\dot{b}}{b}.
\end{align}
Then, I compute the Riemann components (all other components are 0):
\begin{align}
R^0_{i 0 j} &= a \ddot{a} \, g^2 \, \delta_{ij}, \\[12pt]
R^0_{303} &= b \ddot{b}, \\[12pt]
R^i_{33j} &= -\, \frac{\dot{a} \dot{b} b}{a} \, \delta_{ij}, \\[12pt]
R^i_{jkl} &= (\dot{a}^2 g^2 + \mathcal{Q}(r))(\delta_{ki} \, \delta_{lj} - \delta_{li} \, \delta_{kj}) + \text{anisotropic terms}.
\end{align}
The anisotropic terms cancel if
\begin{equation}\tag{3}
\frac{g^{\prime \prime}}{g} = \frac{g^{\prime}}{g \, r} + 2 \frac{g^{\prime 2}}{g^2},
\end{equation}
which implies the solution
\begin{equation}\tag{4}
g(r) = \frac{A}{1 + B \, r^2},
\end{equation}
where $A$ and $B$ are constants (they can be absorbed into the coordinates, so $A = 1$ and $B = -1, 0, 1$ like the parameter $k$ in cosmology).  Then
\begin{equation}\tag{5}
\mathcal{Q}(r) = 4 B \, g^2.
\end{equation}
I then compute the Einstein tensor (again: $i, j = 1, 2$ only):
\begin{align}
G_{00} &= -\, \Big( 2 \frac{\dot{a} \dot{b}}{a b} + \frac{\dot{a}^2}{a^2} + \frac{4 B}{a^2} \Big), \tag{6} \\[12pt]
G_{ij} &= -\, \Big( \frac{\ddot{a}}{a} + \frac{\ddot{b}}{b} + \frac{\dot{a} \dot{b}}{a b} \Big) \, g_{ij}, \tag{7} \\[12pt]
G_{33} &= -\, \Big( 2 \frac{\ddot{a}}{a} + \frac{\dot{a}^2}{a^2} + \frac{4 B}{a^2} \Big) \, g_{33}. \tag{8}
\end{align}
These components are similar (but have some differences) with what we find in the usual spherical FLRW cosmology.

I guess that I need to introduce some anisotropic pressure ($\sigma = p_{\perp}$ in the $x$-$y$ plane and $p = p_{\parallel}$ along the $z$ axis).  Is there any interesting paper on anisotropic-cylindrical cosmologies?

Comment: Would having a conical singularity at $r = 0$ count as not having "artificial" periodic boundaries?  Depending on the behaviour of $g$ as $r \to 0$, this is easy to accomplish.  However, a conical singularity can also be obtained by removing a wedge from a well-behaved spacetime and identifying the "cuts", so it may not be what you're looking for.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert, I'm interested in a regular metric at $r = 0$ (so no conical singularity).  Space should be homogeneous.

Comment: Ah, OK.  If it's regular at $r = 0$, then it would seem to be topologically trivial.  But you used the [tag:topology] tag and wanted the spacetime to be "cylindrical", which is why I'm confused.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're looking for is a spacetime with *local rotational symmetry* (LRS).  These are described in Stefani et. al's *Exact Solutions of Einstein's Field Equations*, Section 13.1.2.  Some references are given there;  the primary ones are:

> Ellis, G.F.R. (1967). *Dynamics of pressure-free matter in general relativity.* J. Math. Phys. **8,** 1171.
>
> Stewart, J.M. and Ellis, G.F.R. (1968). *Solutions of Einstein’s equations for a perfect fluid which exhibit local rotational symmetry.* J. Math. Phys. **9,** 1072.

Ellis & van Elst's [Cargèse lectures from 1998](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9812046) are also helpful if you want to think about such models;  Section 5 goes into some detail about how cosmological models with various amount of symmetry can be constructed.